# How to set zoom level for MS-Edge in IE MODE browser using selenium 3.141.59 on windows 11?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, selenium-iedriver

I am automating a web application in ME-Edge in IE Mode on Windows 11. I have to set zoom level to 80% for same requirement for all end to end test cases. I tried with multiple given code
// To zoom out 3 times

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT));
}
```

Also tried with JavascriptExecutor, but its working for launching page, once logged in and it goes to next page where browser zoom will be 100% again and execution stops.

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       System.out.println("Zoom with 80%");
              jse.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
```

Also, tried with press CTRL+SUBTRACT but script stops further execution.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getDriverPath()
                            + "\\IEDriverServer32bit.exe");
            InternetExplorerOptions edgeIe11Options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            Map<String, Object> ops = (Map<String, Object>) edgeIe11Options.getCapability("se:ieOptions");
            ops.put("ie.edgechromium", true);
            ops.put("ie.edgepath", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");                edgeIe11Options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
            edgeIe11Options.ignoreZoomSettings();
            edgeIe11Options.enablePersistentHovering();
            edgeIe11Options.getBrowserName();
            edgeIe11Options.takeFullPageScreenshot();
            // edgeIe11Options.disableNativeEvents();
            edgeIe11Options.requireWindowFocus();
            edgeIe11Options.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
            edgeIe11Options.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
            edgeIe11Options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
            
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(edgeIe11Options);
```

Comment: @KendrickLi, I have not found any solution as of now. I tried your solution too but it didnt work out for me.

Comment: Hi @Prashant , after some investigation, I haven't found any possible solution yet. So, I think it is necessary to avoid a different zoom level in IE mode automation.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost every possible means of setting the zoom level, but it usually will not cause any issue except when you perform some mouse action. Notes from [Selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/#required-configuration):

> The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse
> events can be set to the correct coordinates.

So I would suggest restoring the browser zoom level to 100% when you need to perform mouse action, and zoom in/out when you actually need it, though it may sound rather complicated.